# Will detaching an instance group from a load balancer make existed connection disconnected?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have an instance group I want to detach from the TCP load balancer, but I don't want existing connections on instances disconnected. I'm wondering if I detach an instance group from the load balancer will make the connection disconnected immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP load balancer as is proxied, terminates customers’ TCP sessions at the load balancer layer, then creates a new connection to forwards the traffic to the instances using TCP or SSL.

As per this TCP Load Balancer [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp/#backend_services) the connection will be terminated “when an instance is terminated, removed manually, or removed by an autoscaler” or manually removed from an instance group.

In order to minimize these interruptions you can enable [Connection Draining](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/enabling-connection-draining) in your backend services. In this case, you shouldn't detach all your backends (instance group) as a timeout is set to migrate traffic from one vm to another. When this happens, existing network sessions are preserved, up to the duration of the connection draining timeout, but the backend service does not route new connections to the VM.

In the following [How-to guide](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/enabling-connection-draining#enabling_connection_draining) you can find how to configure it.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have done some experiments before I saw your answer, the results show that connections remain on the instance after it had been detached from LB. This behavior is as same as you described in section 2, which I just missed in the GCP document, thank you for pointing out. By the way, for the minimum interruption, I attached another instance group to LB before I detach the original one.